# Pros/Cons of different backplane architectures?

Tags: performance

Are there some general resources (other than spec sheets of boards) to compare the differences between computing formats like VPX, VME, IBM bladecenter-h, etc?

I am tasked with doing some legwork what form-factor we should be looking at when buying our processing equipment for a high performance semi-rugged system.

I've read specs on size, connectors, bandwidth density, power usage, etc. Is there anything more I am missing?  I'm having trouble comparing the overall possible bandwidth to each server in each architecture.  Particularly VPX and all of its dot level specifications.

These would run custom software and FPGAs, DACs, ADCs, a linux machine, etc.

Comment: can you add some more detail to your question, why you're after this information etc. it'll help us address it better.

Comment: Seconded - for what use cases do you have, where the bus/backplane architecture matters more than the OS, application software, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Computer_buses
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VPX
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMEbus
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_bus

Comment: So I've read those, but still don't have a general idea of how to differentiate between the them since many of them can use the same switched fabrics.  Is the implementation of the board on that architecture simply the most important?